# Why does my bootstrap navbar get overlapped by page contents when minimized?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar, nav

Here is the website: www.farzadv.ca/wiconnect

When I make the screen size smaller, and collapse the menu, it does not properly show and also the navbar brand is awkwardly placed, how can I change the scaling of that picture and also fix the navbar?

This is the css file:

```css
body{
 background-color: #DAEDFF;
}

.navbar .brand {
max-height: 40px;
padding-top: 0;
padding-bottom: 0;
}

.navbar .nav > li > a, .navbar .nav > li > a:first-letter,
.navbar .nav > li.current-menu-item > a, 
.navbar .nav > li.current-menu-ancestor > a {
 font-style:bold;
}

.navbar a.navbar-brand {padding: 9px 15px 8px; }


.carousel-inner img {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.carousel-control.left, .carousel-control.right {
    color:black;
    background-image: none
}

#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
    color: rgba(119, 119, 119, 1);
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default {
    font-size: 14px;
    background-color: rgba(165, 250, 172, 1);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 0%, rgba(165, 250, 172, 1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 0%, rgba(165, 250, 172, 1) 100%);
    border-width: 1px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
    color: rgba(119, 119, 119, 1);
    background-color: rgba(248, 248, 248, 0);
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover,
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:focus {
    color: rgba(51, 51, 51, 1);
    background-color: rgba(248, 248, 248, 0);
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a,
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover,
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus {
    color: rgba(85, 85, 85, 1);
    background-color: rgba(231, 231, 231, 1);
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
    border-color: #ddd;
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover,
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {
    background-color: #ddd;
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
    background-color: #888;
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover .icon-bar,
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus .icon-bar {
    background-color: #a5faac;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a {
    color: #ecf0f1;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
    color: #4f4f4f;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a:focus {
    color: #4f4f4f;
    background-color: #57fb80;
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried making the brand logo responsive using: class="img-responsive", except it already has the class of: class="navbar-brand"

edit: max-width:100%; height:auto;" is also not working.

Answer (score 0):

The navbar issue is due to missing the role="button" properties on the two dropdown-toggle links. As for the picture, I find it is usually easier to implement images in css through "background-image" styles. In order to make it cover that whole navbar-brand div, you first assign the background-image, then you use "background-size: cover" in order to fill the div. After that just give that div a specific height and width, and it's good to go.